# Most efficient way to generate XML payload in Java

Tags: java, xml, performance

In my application I have a REST endpoint (/processRequest) where I am receiving several parameters (clientId,channelId,opId). These parameters are then used to generate a XML payload with this structure:

```
<eCommerceDoc>
   <clientId>5</clientId>
   <channelId>2</channelId>
   <opId>opIdString</opId>
</eCommerceDoc>
```

In the code it looks like this:

```
@RestController public class RequestController {

@RequestMapping(value="/processRequest")
public String processRequest(
        @RequestParam("clientId")int clientId,
        @RequestParam("channelId")int channelId,
        @RequestParam("opId")String opId
        
        ) {

    String xml = 
            "<eCommerceDoc>" 
            +"<clientId>" + clientId + "</clientId>" 
            +"<channelId>" + channelId + "</channelId>" 
            +"<opId>" + opId + "</opId>" 
            +"</eCommerceDoc>";

    sendXMLtoAnotherSystem(xml);
```

The problem with this is that the memory is getting filled really fast, I can see that for each request to this endpoint a new String is saved in memory:

[image]

In this image we can see that last 2 Strings are the ones which are interned, and first 2 were generated because I triggered 2 requests for this example.

The problem is when doing stress testing, even without a big load these Strings are filling the heap too quickly, causing a lot of Minor Gcs, so my question is if there is a better approach to generate the XML dinamically (using SAX or some framework)? All the questions I have found are about Parsing but in this case I need to generate the actual XML because it is sent to another System. Thanks for the help.

Comment: It is VERY likely that at one point or another, any XML generation and transmission approach will eventually have the XML as a Java String object. And as Strings can't be re-used with different content, they'll get GC'ed. That's the way Java works, and its well-optimized GC is designed to handle such cases. All that will be much faster than the HTTP transfer.

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java_xml/java_dom_create_document.htm

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky wow you are so helpful, think I didn't find anything like that many times? do you even know how it performs in terms of memory ?

Answer (score 1):

Before you worry about the performance of this code, you should worry about its correctness. At present it's wrong: it fails to look for special characters such as "&" and "<" in the data and escape them as XML requires. We get a lot of posts on StackOverflow from people asking how to repair XML that's been generated carelessly like this!

It's better to generate XML using a library rather than just by string concatenation, even though it won't give you a performance improvement for tiny XML documents like this - though it might if you start generating XML documents that are more substantial.

Comment: Hi Michael, first of all thank you for your response... I would like to add that I crated this example for simplicity and because I cannot paste here real business code, but the overlying idea is the same, the XML is generated dinamically, appending the values as shown above, except that in real life it has 15+tags and it is much larger, so I was wondering if it would be a better idea to use StringBuilder instead of concatenating the fields like that, using "+", or if some other XML framework would help, because it is filling the memory quickly... thank you so much...